# Chartjs pie chart, radial displacement (offset)

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

Does Chartjs 2 support radial displacement (offset) of pie segments?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chart.js alone does not have option to cut a piece out like this. But you can always [define your own chart type](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-writing-new-chart-types)!

Here I subclass the `pie` chart into a `cutOutPie` type. The chart class configures the "pie slices" using the `updateElement` function, so I overwrite it and shift the elements' position.  Details can be found by [reading the source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js).

```js
Chart.defaults.cutOutPie = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.pie);

Chart.controllers.cutOutPie = Chart.controllers.pie.extend({
    updateElement: function(arc, index, reset) {
        Chart.controllers.pie.prototype.updateElement.call(this, arc, index, reset);
        var displacement = this.getDataset().displacements[index]||0;
        var model = arc._model;
        var angle = model.startAngle + model.circumference/2;
        model.x += Math.cos(angle) * displacement;
        model.y += Math.sin(angle) * displacement;
    }
});

new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'cutOutPie',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'gold', 'pink', 'blue'],
            displacements: [0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 16],
        }],
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually playing around with the Javascript, it's thankfully easy to figure out where to hack. But thanks for giving a perfect example showing how to do it clean!

Comment: It works great, except one thing: Displaced pie segments fall outside the chart area, so they are cropped. Either the area has to be extended to make room (wrt the largest displacement given), or the radius of the pie has to be reduced similarily. I assume either will have the same result, visually? I tried reducing `this.chart.outerRadius` etc, within your `updateElement`, but nothing changes.

Comment: You could try [`Chart.defaults.global.layout = {padding: 100}`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-layout-configuration) as a quick workaround, but that will reduce the size of the whole chart.

Comment: That does work, thanks! Still -- isn't it possible to "simply" change the radius, i.e. the length of each segment?

Comment: @joakimk I'd say that's worth a new question.

Comment: Sure, I was just thinking it seems like an important part of your nice new cutOutPie type (which is why I kept this here, rather than making a new question). Not very easy to use the cutOutPie when the chart gets cropped :)

Comment: @joakimk how would you do the xact same in chart.js v4?