# Chartjs v4 pie chart, radial displacement (offset)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Basically I'm trying to achieve the exact same as this question but in V4 :
[Chartjs pie chart, radial displacement (offset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724126/chartjs-pie-chart-radial-displacement-offset#_=)_

This code answer works in v2.6, can anyone guide me with the format of that for v4.

```
Chart.defaults.cutOutPie = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.pie);

Chart.controllers.cutOutPie = Chart.controllers.pie.extend({
    updateElement: function(arc, index, reset) {
        Chart.controllers.pie.prototype.updateElement.call(this, arc, index, reset);
        var displacement = this.getDataset().displacements[index]||0;
        var model = arc._model;
        var angle = model.startAngle + model.circumference/2;
        model.x += Math.cos(angle) * displacement;
        model.y += Math.sin(angle) * displacement;
    }
});

new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'cutOutPie',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'gold', 'pink', 'blue'],
            displacements: [0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 16],
        }],
    },
});
```

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

I understand how to do it if Im packaging building in react or vue but not how to do the same thing in browse.

The docs seem to only talk about import and class.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript v4, uses ecmascript classes so custom controllers should be subclasses of existing ones, overwriting relevant methods, as summarly described in the ["New Charts" section of the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html).

Thus, an analogous of the older code would be:

```js
const PieController = Chart.controllers.pie;

class CutOutPie extends PieController{
    static id = 'cutOutPie';

    updateElement(arc, index, properties, mode) {
        const displacement = this.getDataset().displacements?.[index] || 0;
        if(displacement && properties.circumference){
            const angle = properties.startAngle + properties.circumference/2;
            properties.x += displacement * Math.cos(angle);
            properties.y += displacement * Math.sin(angle);
        }
        if(properties.outerRadius){
            properties.outerRadius -= Math.max(...this.chart.data.datasets[0].displacements);
        }
        super.updateElement(arc, index, properties, mode);
    }
}

Chart.register(CutOutPie);

new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'cutOutPie',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'gold', 'pink', 'blue'],
            displacements: [0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 26],
        }]
    },
    options:{
        responsive: true,
        animation:{
            duration: 500,
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<body>
<div style="height:500px; width: 500px">
<canvas id="chart" style="border: 1px solid #999"></canvas>
</div>
```

The radii of the slices had to be scaled down in order to avoid displaced slices to extend outside of the canvas or overlap the legend or other elements.

Here's a slightly more elaborate version, that precomputes the displacements and takes into consideration standard animations:

```js
const PieController = Chart.registry.controllers.get('pie');
//this seems to be the most general way to get the controller class
// alternatives, depending on environment:
// PieController = Chart.PieController;
// PieController = Chart.controllers.pie;
// import {PieController} from 'chart.js';

class CutOutPie extends PieController{
    static id = 'cutOutPie';
    static defaults = {
        displacements: []
    }

    initialize(){
        super.initialize();
        this._displacementOffset = 0;
        this._offsetsValid = false;
        this._arcProperties = [];
    }

    updateElements(arcs, start, count, mode){
        this._offsetsValid = false;
        this._arcProperties = [];
        super.updateElements(arcs, start, count, mode);

        if(!this._offsetsValid){
            this._computeDisplacementOffsets(arcs);
            for(let i = start; i < start + count; i++){
                this.updateElement(arcs[i], i, {}, mode);
            }
        }
    }

    _computeDisplacementOffsets(arcs){
        if(Number.isFinite(this._arcProperties?.[0]?.outerRadius)){
            let startAngle = this._getRotation();
            for(let i = 0; i < arcs.length; i++){
                const displacement = this.getDataset().displacements?.[i] || 0;
                const endAngle = startAngle + this._circumference(i);
                this._arcProperties[i] = Object.assign(this._arcProperties[i] || {}, {dx: 0, dy: 0, shrink: 1});
                if(displacement){
                    const angle = (startAngle + endAngle)/2;
                    this._arcProperties[i].dx = Math.cos(angle) * displacement;
                    this._arcProperties[i].dy = Math.sin(angle) * displacement;
                    this._displacementOffset = Math.max(this._displacementOffset, displacement);
                }
                startAngle = endAngle;
            }

            for(let i = 0; i < arcs.length; i++){
                const outerRadius = this._arcProperties[i].outerRadius || this.outerRadius;
                if(outerRadius){
                    this._arcProperties[i].shrink =  (outerRadius - this._displacementOffset)/outerRadius ;
                }
            }
            this._offsetsValid = true;
        }
    }

    updateElement(arc, index, properties, mode) {
        this._arcProperties[index] = this._arcProperties[index] || {};
        Object.assign(this._arcProperties[index], properties || {});
        const animation = this.options.animation.animateRotate || this.options.animation.animateScale;
        if(this._offsetsValid){
            if(mode !== 'reset' || !animation){
                if(this._arcProperties[index].hasOwnProperty('dx')){
                    this._arcProperties[index].x += this._arcProperties[index].dx;
                }
                if(this._arcProperties[index].hasOwnProperty('dy')){
                    this._arcProperties[index].y += this._arcProperties[index].dy;
                }
                arc.x = this._arcProperties[index].x - this._arcProperties[index].dx;
                arc.y = this._arcProperties[index].y - this._arcProperties[index].dy;
            }
            const shrink = this._arcProperties[index].shrink;
            if(shrink){
                this._arcProperties[index].outerRadius *= shrink;
                this._arcProperties[index].innerRadius *= shrink;
            }
            super.updateElement(arc, index, this._arcProperties[index], mode);
        }
    }
}

Chart.register(CutOutPie);

new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'cutOutPie',
    data: {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9],
            backgroundColor: ['red', 'orange', 'green', 'gold', 'pink', 'blue'],
            displacements: [0, 0, 40, 0, 0, 26],
        }]
    },
    options:{
        responsive: true,
        animation:{
            duration: 500,
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div style="height:500px; width: 500px">
<canvas id="chart" style="border: 1px solid #999"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-t41WshQCxr9T3SWH3DBZoDnAT9gfVLtQS+NKO60fdAwScoB37rXtdxT/oKe986G0BFnP4mtGzXxuYpHrMoMJLA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```